# Chainlink VRFCoordinator taking a long time to respond

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, chainlink

This is a blockchain question. I'm following the tutorial from freecodecamp and every time we use the vrfcoordinator from chainlink it works perfectly in the development network, but not when I deploy my smart contract to the rinkeby test net.

My issue is when I try to get a verified random number from the VRFcoordinator(0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B) it takes about 40 minutes to get a response back.

Is this normal? or is it because I'm deploying it to a test-net

If so, is this the best way to get a random number considering it takes 40 minutes to get one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks [like Rinkeby is down](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) (as of writing this answer the last Rinekby block was mined almost 9 hours ago.) You'll have to wait for Rinkeby to come back online.